# How to get html generated from javascript using phantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status === 'fail') {
        console.log("fail");
    } else {
        console.log(page.evaluate(function () {
            var t0 = document.body.innerHTML;
            return t0;

        }));
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

When I do this way, I can't get the html generated from js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to return anything from the page scope to the phantom's scope.

You should consider using

window.callPhantom method and page.onCallback event.

Comment: That helps me.But evaluate sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't work?

Comment: What problems do you face?

Comment: I got it. It's because of Dom tree generating without 'WaitTimeout'.